# cannot load mysql from terminal but can start mysql with system preferences

Tags: mysql

I understand that this question has been asked several times before, I have been through many solutions and thus far nothing has worked.

There is definitely something wrong with the directory MySQL is trying to install itself into (usr/local/mysql). The weird thing about my error is that I am able to start my server from system prefrences with the mySQLprefPanel manager..

I have tried reinstalling the database, using the command prompt to edit files that define the location of mysql using terminal to change directorys all sorts..

However I cannot access it with mysql -u root -p command in terminal... this leaves me with "command not found error..."

Are there any solutions that you know of that might benefit my particular problem so I can start setting up my databases.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Mysql comes in two parts. Mysqld is the server process and runs in the background. mysql is the client process which you execute when you want to connect to mysql server in the terminal.

Comment: I am using OSX 10.6 and what your saying kinda makes sense because I can run my server from system prefrences howeve I cannot do anything with it like initalizing new tables etc because I cant access it in a terminal

Comment: OSX? Me too and I've had goofy problems with Terminal all week. This is going to sound weird but check your Terminal encodings. I had to wipe my plist (drag it to desktop, restart terminal with only UTF8) to fix it. Character encodings became escape signals. In my case, this mangled the server conf files of the brand new remote Centos server I've been trying to install for myself and my team so badly that the box bricked. Twice. :( So it's worth a check, at least...

Comment: hrmm... I will look into it but I have been doing all my editing in the terminal so pretty sure there is no character encoding going into any of my files.. but seriously this is such a pain in the ars because it could be a number of different problems and as you try to work through them to figure out whats going on you can stuff something up that you think you are actually fixing that will give you problems later on :P

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities that I can think of:
 **1. Improper installation:**
 goto the location where you have installed Mysql and then look in the /bin folder if you have got "mysql". If you have mysql, then please refer next possiblity 
 **2. Not running as a service:**
  In this case, if you are using linux, check with *netstat -a* which would give you list of running services. Check if you have mysql service running with port:3306 (or whatever you have assigned it to). If it is not running, please install mysql as a service. You can find lot of tutorial on it.

Comment: yes mysql is in the bin file, I am using a mac.. so will need to find out how to do what you said with linux.

Comment: so I ran netstat and this was the only mysql thing running
         6a9b320 stream      0      0          9d2e940                0                0                0 /tmp/mysql.sock

dosnt tell me what port its running in however.

Comment: ports and sockets are unrelated mechanisms, mysql can accepts connections on a port (tcp port 3306 by default) or a socket (special file), or both. Binary mac installations are set up to accept connections based on the socket.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is going to be an incomplete answer - I'll fill in th rest when I get home tonight.

I had a similar problem and I had to create a symbolic link to point to `/tmp/mysql.sock` *somewhere* (this bit to follow). For whatever reason the installation I used was not pointing at the `/tmp` directory, and rather than copying the files from tmp to (other) I just created a sym-link in the correct directory that pointed to `/tmp`

Can I suggest also that you download the mysql GUI [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads). I found this to be a much better way of managing your database rather than through the terminal.

**UPDATE:** I've just found where mine is situated:
the `mysql.sock` file is at `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` on my macbook air. 
the `mysql` file is at `/usr/local/mysql` along with another file `mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64`

Comment: yea I found the work bench after I posted this question, and have been working with that to try and solve my problems but to be honest its giving me errors that are not really related to my current problems.. I cannot create new databases and a bunch of other errors.. man what a mess... starting to feel like its abit of a lost cause. Might reinstall and give it another crack for the 100th time :P

Comment: So I now have it to a point where working with the work bench, I can create a new server instance with the work bench, but then when I try to run any queries on it, it craps out...

Comment: just updated. Check the location of all these files that I mention.